# The Latest angular-fullstack-generator Is Missing the glyphicons-halflings-regular Fonts in the gulp serve:dist? Why?

Tags: gulp, angular-fullstack, isparta

I have a large project based on the angular-fullstack-generator, and when I run:

```
gulp serve:dist
```

I see:

```
GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 404 0.739 ms - 14
GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 404 0.739 ms - 14
GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 1.023 ms - 14
GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 1.023 ms - 14
```

And because these fonts are missing, I also see:

```
2016-06-22T13:23:22-0600 <error> index.js:19 () { [Error: Failed to lookup view "404" in views directory ".../dist/server/views"] ...}
```

I corrected this by adding the following to gulpfile.babel.js:

```
gulp.task('copy:fonts-extras', () => {
  return gulp.src([`${clientPath}/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/*`], { dot: true })     .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/`));
});
```

And I placed this just after the copy:fonts entry in the 'build' task.

This seems a bit dumb, since these fonts are already in the bootstrap/fonts/ directory, but that isn't where the code is attempting to access them, and it wasn't obvious (to me) where in the code to change this path.

At the same time, the 'production' build does not copy the views directory (which only contains the 404.html file).

So I also added:

```
gulp.task('copy:views', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'server/views/*'
  ], { dot: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/server/views/`));
});
```

And I added the copy:views is the same place I added copy:fonts-extra.

Is there a better way to correct these problems?

I am using the latest version of the angular-fullstack-generator v3.7.6.

Perhaps the beta2 corrects this?

Here is resultant gulpfile.babel.js:

```
// Generated on 2016-06-21 using generator-angular-fullstack 3.7.6
'use strict';

import _ from 'lodash';
import del from 'del';
import gulp from 'gulp';
import grunt from 'grunt';
import path from 'path';
import gulpLoadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import http from 'http';
import open from 'open';
import lazypipe from 'lazypipe';
import {stream as wiredep} from 'wiredep';
import nodemon from 'nodemon';
import {Server as KarmaServer} from 'karma';
import runSequence from 'run-sequence';
import {protractor, webdriver_update} from 'gulp-protractor';
import {Instrumenter} from 'isparta';

var plugins = gulpLoadPlugins();
var config;

const clientPath = require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client';
const serverPath = 'server';
const paths = {
    client: {
        assets: `${clientPath}/assets/**/*`,
        images: `${clientPath}/assets/images/**/*`,
        scripts: [
            `${clientPath}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).js`,
            `!${clientPath}/bower_components/**/*`
        ],
        styles: [`${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.scss`],
        mainStyle: `${clientPath}/app/app.scss`,
        views: `${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.html`,
        mainView: `${clientPath}/index.html`,
        test: [`${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.{spec,mock}.js`],
        e2e: ['e2e/**/*.spec.js'],
        bower: `${clientPath}/bower_components/`
    },
    server: {
        scripts: [
          `${serverPath}/**/!(*.spec|*.integration).js`,
          `!${serverPath}/config/local.env.sample.js`
        ],
        json: [`${serverPath}/**/*.json`],
        test: {
          integration: [`${serverPath}/**/*.integration.js`, 'mocha.global.js'],
          unit: [`${serverPath}/**/*.spec.js`, 'mocha.global.js']
        }
    },
    karma: 'karma.conf.js',
    dist: 'dist'
};

/********************
 * Helper functions
 ********************/

function onServerLog(log) {
    console.log(plugins.util.colors.white('[') +
        plugins.util.colors.yellow('nodemon') +
        plugins.util.colors.white('] ') +
        log.message);
}

function checkAppReady(cb) {
    var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: config.port
    };
    http
        .get(options, () => cb(true))
        .on('error', () => cb(false));
}

// Call page until first success
function whenServerReady(cb) {
    var serverReady = false;
    var appReadyInterval = setInterval(() =>
        checkAppReady((ready) => {
            if (!ready || serverReady) {
                return;
            }
            clearInterval(appReadyInterval);
            serverReady = true;
            cb();
        }),
        100);
}

function sortModulesFirst(a, b) {
    var module = /\.module\.js$/;
    var aMod = module.test(a.path);
    var bMod = module.test(b.path);
    // inject *.module.js first
    if (aMod === bMod) {
        // either both modules or both non-modules, so just sort normally
        if (a.path < b.path) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.path > b.path) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (aMod ? -1 : 1);
    }
}

/********************
 * Reusable pipelines
 ********************/

let lintClientScripts = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.jshint, `${clientPath}/.jshintrc`)
    .pipe(plugins.jshint.reporter, 'jshint-stylish');

let lintServerScripts = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.jshint, `${serverPath}/.jshintrc`)
    .pipe(plugins.jshint.reporter, 'jshint-stylish');

let lintServerTestScripts = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.jshint, `${serverPath}/.jshintrc-spec`)
    .pipe(plugins.jshint.reporter, 'jshint-stylish');

let styles = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init)
    .pipe(plugins.sass)

    .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer, {browsers: ['last 1 version']})
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write, '.');

let transpileClient = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init)
    .pipe(plugins.babel)
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write, '.');

let transpileServer = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init)
    .pipe(plugins.babel, {
        plugins: [
            'transform-class-properties',
            'transform-runtime'
        ]
    })
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write, '.');

let mocha = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.mocha, {
        reporter: 'spec',
        timeout: 5000,
        require: [
            './mocha.conf'
        ]
    });

let istanbul = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.istanbul.writeReports)
    .pipe(plugins.istanbulEnforcer, {
        thresholds: {
            global: {
                lines: 80,
                statements: 80,
                branches: 80,
                functions: 80
            }
        },
        coverageDirectory: './coverage',
        rootDirectory : ''
    });

/********************
 * Env
 ********************/

gulp.task('env:all', () => {
    let localConfig;
    try {
        localConfig = require(`./${serverPath}/config/local.env`);
    } catch (e) {
        localConfig = {};
    }
    plugins.env({
        vars: localConfig
    });
});
gulp.task('env:test', () => {
    plugins.env({
        vars: {NODE_ENV: 'test'}
    });
});
gulp.task('env:prod', () => {
    plugins.env({
        vars: {NODE_ENV: 'production'}
    });
});

/********************
 * Tasks
 ********************/

gulp.task('inject', cb => {
    runSequence(['inject:js', 'inject:css', 'inject:scss'], cb);
});

gulp.task('inject:js', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainView)
        .pipe(plugins.inject(
            gulp.src(_.union(paths.client.scripts, [`!${clientPath}/**/*.{spec,mock}.js`, `!${clientPath}/app/app.js`]), {read: false})
                .pipe(plugins.sort(sortModulesFirst)),
            {
                starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
                endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->',
                transform: (filepath) => '<script src="' + filepath.replace(`/${clientPath}/`, '') + '"></script>'
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(clientPath));
});

gulp.task('inject:css', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainView)
        .pipe(plugins.inject(
            gulp.src(`${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.css`, {read: false})
                .pipe(plugins.sort()),
            {
                starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
                endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->',
                transform: (filepath) => '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filepath.replace(`/${clientPath}/`, '').replace('/.tmp/', '') + '">'
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(clientPath));
});

gulp.task('inject:scss', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainStyle)
        .pipe(plugins.inject(
            gulp.src(_.union(paths.client.styles, ['!' + paths.client.mainStyle]), {read: false})
                .pipe(plugins.sort()),
            {
                transform: (filepath) => {
                    let newPath = filepath
                        .replace(`/${clientPath}/app/`, '')
                        .replace(`/${clientPath}/components/`, '../components/')
                        .replace(/_(.*).scss/, (match, p1, offset, string) => p1)
                        .replace('.scss', '');
                    return `@import '${newPath}';`;
                }
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${clientPath}/app`));
});

gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainStyle)
        .pipe(styles())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/app'));
});

gulp.task('transpile:client', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.scripts)
        .pipe(transpileClient())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));
});

gulp.task('transpile:server', () => {
    return gulp.src(_.union(paths.server.scripts, paths.server.json))
        .pipe(transpileServer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${serverPath}`));
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts', cb => runSequence(['lint:scripts:client', 'lint:scripts:server'], cb));

gulp.task('lint:scripts:client', () => {
    return gulp.src(_.union(
        paths.client.scripts,
        _.map(paths.client.test, blob => '!' + blob),
        [`!${clientPath}/app/app.constant.js`]
    ))
        .pipe(lintClientScripts());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts:server', () => {
    return gulp.src(_.union(paths.server.scripts, _.map(paths.server.test, blob => '!' + blob)))
        .pipe(lintServerScripts());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts:clientTest', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.test)
        .pipe(lintClientScripts());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts:serverTest', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test)
        .pipe(lintServerTestScripts());
});

gulp.task('jscs', () => {
  return gulp.src(_.union(paths.client.scripts, paths.server.scripts))
      .pipe(plugins.jscs())
      .pipe(plugins.jscs.reporter());
});

gulp.task('clean:tmp', () => del(['.tmp/**/*'], {dot: true}));

gulp.task('start:client', cb => {
    whenServerReady(() => {
        open('http://localhost:' + config.port);
        cb();
    });
});

gulp.task('start:server', () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    config = require(`./${serverPath}/config/environment`);
    nodemon(`-w ${serverPath} ${serverPath}`)
        .on('log', onServerLog);
});

gulp.task('start:server:prod', () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
    config = require(`./${paths.dist}/${serverPath}/config/environment`);
    nodemon(`-w ${paths.dist}/${serverPath} ${paths.dist}/${serverPath}`)
        .on('log', onServerLog);
});

gulp.task('start:inspector', () => {
    gulp.src([])
        .pipe(plugins.nodeInspector());
});

gulp.task('start:server:debug', () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
        config = require(`./${serverPath}/config/environment`);
    nodemon(`-w ${serverPath} --debug-brk ${serverPath}`)
        .on('log', onServerLog);
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    var testFiles = _.union(paths.client.test, paths.server.test.unit, paths.server.test.integration);

    plugins.livereload.listen();

    plugins.watch(paths.client.styles, () => {  //['inject:scss']
        gulp.src(paths.client.mainStyle)
            .pipe(plugins.plumber())
            .pipe(styles())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/app'))
            .pipe(plugins.livereload());
    });

    plugins.watch(paths.client.views)
        .pipe(plugins.plumber())
        .pipe(plugins.livereload());

    plugins.watch(paths.client.scripts) //['inject:js']
        .pipe(plugins.plumber())
        .pipe(transpileClient())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
        .pipe(plugins.livereload());

    plugins.watch(_.union(paths.server.scripts, testFiles))
        .pipe(plugins.plumber())
        .pipe(lintServerScripts())
        .pipe(plugins.livereload());

    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep:client']);
});

gulp.task('serve', cb => {
    runSequence(['clean:tmp', 'constant', 'env:all'],
        ['lint:scripts', 'inject'],
        ['wiredep:client'],
        ['transpile:client', 'styles'],
        ['start:server', 'start:client'],
        'watch',
        cb);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', cb => {
    runSequence(
        'build',
        'env:all',
        'env:prod',
        ['start:server:prod', 'start:client'],
        cb);
});

gulp.task('serve:debug', cb => {
    runSequence(['clean:tmp', 'constant'],
        ['lint:scripts', 'inject'],
        ['wiredep:client'],
        ['transpile:client', 'styles'],
        'start:inspector',
        ['start:server:debug', 'start:client'],
        'watch',
        cb);
});

gulp.task('test', cb => {
    return runSequence('test:server', 'test:client', cb);
});

gulp.task('test:server', cb => {
    runSequence(
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'mocha:unit',
        'mocha:integration',
        'mocha:coverage',
        cb);
});

gulp.task('mocha:unit', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test.unit)
        .pipe(mocha());
});

gulp.task('mocha:integration', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test.integration)
        .pipe(mocha());
});

gulp.task('test:client', ['wiredep:test', 'constant'], (done) => {
    new KarmaServer({
      configFile: `${__dirname}/${paths.karma}`,
      singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});

// inject bower components
gulp.task('wiredep:client', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainView)
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /bootstrap.js/,
                '/json3/',
                '/es5-shim/',
                /font-awesome\.css/,
                /bootstrap\.css/,
                /bootstrap-sass-official/,
                /bootstrap-social\.css/
            ],
            ignorePath: clientPath
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${clientPath}/`));
});

gulp.task('wiredep:test', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.karma)
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /bootstrap.js/,
                '/json3/',
                '/es5-shim/',
                /font-awesome\.css/,
                /bootstrap\.css/,
                /bootstrap-sass-official/,
                /bootstrap-social\.css/
            ],
            devDependencies: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

/********************
 * Build
 ********************/

//FIXME: looks like font-awesome isn't getting loaded
gulp.task('build', cb => {
    runSequence(
        [
            'clean:dist',
            'clean:tmp'
        ],
        'inject',
        'wiredep:client',
        [
            'transpile:client',
            'transpile:server'
        ],
        [
            'build:images',
            'copy:extras',
            'copy:fonts',
            'copy:fonts-extras',
            'copy:views',
            'copy:assets',
            'copy:server',
            'build:client'
        ],
        cb);
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', () => del([`${paths.dist}/!(.git*|.openshift|Procfile)**`], {dot: true}));

gulp.task('build:client', ['styles', 'html', 'constant', 'build:images'], () => {
    var manifest = gulp.src(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets/rev-manifest.json`);

    var appFilter = plugins.filter('**/app.js', {restore: true});
    var jsFilter = plugins.filter('**/*.js', {restore: true});
    var cssFilter = plugins.filter('**/*.css', {restore: true});
    var htmlBlock = plugins.filter(['**/*.!(html)'], {restore: true});

    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainView)
        .pipe(plugins.useref())
            .pipe(appFilter)
                .pipe(plugins.addSrc.append('.tmp/templates.js'))
                .pipe(plugins.concat('app/app.js'))
            .pipe(appFilter.restore)
            .pipe(jsFilter)
                .pipe(plugins.ngAnnotate())
                .pipe(plugins.uglify())
            .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
            .pipe(cssFilter)
                .pipe(plugins.cleanCss({
                    processImportFrom: ['!fonts.googleapis.com']
                }))
            .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
            .pipe(htmlBlock)
                .pipe(plugins.rev())
            .pipe(htmlBlock.restore)
        .pipe(plugins.revReplace({manifest}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}`));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src(`${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.html`)
        .pipe(plugins.angularTemplatecache({
            module: 'tracker2App'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));
});

gulp.task('constant', function() {
  let sharedConfig = require(`./${serverPath}/config/environment/shared`);
  return plugins.ngConstant({
    name: 'tracker2App.constants',
    deps: [],
    wrap: true,
    stream: true,
    constants: { appConfig: sharedConfig }
  })
    .pipe(plugins.rename({
      basename: 'app.constant'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${clientPath}/app/`))
});

gulp.task('build:images', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.images)
        .pipe(plugins.imagemin({
            optimizationLevel: 5,
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets/images`))
        .pipe(plugins.rev.manifest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets/rev-manifest.json`, {
            base: `${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets`,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets`));
});

gulp.task('copy:extras', () => {
    return gulp.src([
        `${clientPath}/favicon.ico`,
        `${clientPath}/robots.txt`,
        `${clientPath}/.htaccess`
    ], { dot: true })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}`));
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts', () => {
    return gulp.src([
      `${clientPath}/bower_components/{bootstrap,font-awesome}/fonts/**/*`
    ], { dot: true })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/bower_components`));
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts-extras', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    `${clientPath}/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/*`
  ], { dot: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/`));
});

gulp.task('copy:views', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'server/views/*'
  ], { dot: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/server/views/`));
});

gulp.task('copy:assets', () => {
    return gulp.src([paths.client.assets, '!' + paths.client.images])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets`));
});

gulp.task('copy:server', () => {
    return gulp.src([
        'package.json',
        'bower.json',
        '.bowerrc'
    ], {cwdbase: true})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('coverage:pre', () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.server.scripts)
    // Covering files
    .pipe(plugins.istanbul({
        instrumenter: Instrumenter, // Use the isparta instrumenter (code coverage for ES6)
        includeUntested: true
    }))
    // Force `require` to return covered files
    .pipe(plugins.istanbul.hookRequire());
});

gulp.task('coverage:unit', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test.unit)
        .pipe(mocha())
        .pipe(istanbul())
        // Creating the reports after tests ran
});

gulp.task('coverage:integration', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test.integration)
        .pipe(mocha())
        .pipe(istanbul())
        // Creating the reports after tests ran
});

gulp.task('mocha:coverage', cb => {
  runSequence('coverage:pre',
              'env:all',
              'env:test',
              'coverage:unit',
              'coverage:integration',
              cb);
});

// Downloads the selenium webdriver
gulp.task('webdriver_update', webdriver_update);

gulp.task('test:e2e', ['env:all', 'env:test', 'start:server', 'webdriver_update'], cb => {
    gulp.src(paths.client.e2e)
        .pipe(protractor({
            configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
        })).on('error', err => {
            console.log(err)
        }).on('end', () => {
            process.exit();
        });
});

/********************
 * Grunt ported tasks
 ********************/

grunt.initConfig({
    buildcontrol: {
        options: {
            dir: paths.dist,
            commit: true,
            push: true,
            connectCommits: false,
            message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
        },
        heroku: {
            options: {
                remote: 'heroku',
                branch: 'master'
            }
        },
        openshift: {
            options: {
                remote: 'openshift',
                branch: 'master'
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-build-control');

gulp.task('buildcontrol:heroku', function(done) {
    grunt.tasks(
        ['buildcontrol:heroku'],    //you can add more grunt tasks in this array
        {gruntfile: false}, //don't look for a Gruntfile - there is none. :-)
        function() {done();}
    );
});
gulp.task('buildcontrol:openshift', function(done) {
    grunt.tasks(
        ['buildcontrol:openshift'],    //you can add more grunt tasks in this array
        {gruntfile: false}, //don't look for a Gruntfile - there is none. :-)
        function() {done();}
    );
});
```